# python-docx does not apply font size when changing text direction to RTL

Tags: python, ms-word, right-to-left, python-docx

I want to change the direction to RTL since I write in Kurdish which uses Arabic numerals.
but whenever I apply `run.font.rtl = True`, it will cancel the font size `run.font.size = Pt(20)`

How can I fix that issue?

```
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    if '{text}' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{text}', text[i].strip())
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            run.font.size = Pt(20)
            run.font.name = 'Arial'
            run.font.rtl = True
```

Comment: As a possible workaround that wouldn't involve modifying Python-docx itself, what happens if you set the size after setting .rtl = True?

Comment: it does not work, I've tried it

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work, and there have been one or two "issue" reports on the python-docx repository on Github, but not much follow-up. From my experiments here so far, it looks as if the correct <w:rtl/> elements are being inserted in the run's <w:rPr> element, but that Word isn't recognising them. But that is as far as I have got...

Comment: So there is no possible solution?

Comment: I don't think there is a simple solution without modifying Python-docx.

Comment: OK, I was finally able to do some more tests. python-docx is correctly inserting the <w:rtl/> element and the regular <w:sz w:val="40"> element. *But* if you apply RTL formatting and 20pt formatting to the run in Word using VBA, Word inserts an extra size element for the "complex script", <w:szCs w:val="40"> . python-docx does not insert that, and that is why it looks as if it has not changed anything. It looks to me as if people maintaining python-dox have looked at similar issues (e.g. where you need more than one element to specify Bold) but...

Comment: I just found the solution, I added it as the answer and it works!. thanks for your help.

Comment: ...have not yet done the analysis necessary to fix all similar issues. That looks like a really major effort TBH so I am not surprised!

Comment: Well done on finding a fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the **solution** I found, just add this method inside your code and pass it your **run** and other requirement parameters.

```
def fix_cs_formatting_runs( run_to_fix ,user_cs_font_size, user_cs_font_name, user_is_bold ):  #cs: complex script, ex, arabic
    rpr = run_to_fix.element.get_or_add_rPr()
    rFonts = rpr.get_or_add_rFonts()
    rpr.get_or_add_sz()
    szCs = OxmlElement('w:szCs') # size
    sz= OxmlElement('w:sz') # size
    rpr.append(szCs)
    rpr.append(sz)
    lang = OxmlElement('w:lang') #language
    rpr.append(lang)
    if user_is_bold:
        bCs = OxmlElement('w:bCs') #bold the complex language
        rpr.append(bCs)
        bCs.set(qn('w:val'), "True")
        b = OxmlElement('w:b')  # bold the english
        rpr.append(b)
        b.set(qn('w:val'), "True")
    sz.set(qn('w:val'), str(int(user_cs_font_size * 2)))
    szCs.set(qn('w:val'), str(int(user_cs_font_size * 2)))
    lang.set(qn('w:bidi'), 'ar-SA')
    rFonts.set(qn('w:cs'), user_cs_font_name)
    rFonts.set(qn('w:ascii'), user_cs_font_name) #you can change the font for the other language
    rFonts.set(qn('w:hAnsi'), user_cs_font_name) #you can change the font for the other language
```

**Example:**

```
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    if '{text}' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{text}', text[i].strip())
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            fix_cs_formatting_runs(run,20,"Arial",False)
            font = run.font
            font.name = 'Arial'
            font.cs_size = Pt(20)
            font.rtl = True
```